# PHP javascript call with PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, html

Good day, I am having a very odd error with my PHP code. I am attempting to dynamically change the content of my webpage by reading from an xml file. I read in some data and assign the data to a PHP variable called $course_title and then attempt to call some Javascript that will update the "innerHTML" of a DOM element. Note: on the line "echo $course_title;' that prints out the correct data to the screen.

```
$fn = dirname(__FILE__)."/course.xml";  
$xml = simplexml_load_file($fn);
$course_bookimagelocation = "";
foreach ($xml->children() as $child)
{
    if($child[0]->getName()=="book")
        $course_bookimagelocation = $child;
    if($child[0]->getName()=="title")
        $course_title = $child;
}   
//Problems start here...
echo $course_title;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "';
echo $course_title;
echo '";</script>';
```

What is very unique is that the first echo statement prints the correct information, but the next three lines, the .innerHTML does not get changed to that same value. Does anyone know what that is? What is also weird is that if I replace the second "echo '$course_title';" with something like 'Hello world!' then "Hello World!" appears as the innerHTML of the "heading" id object.

**EDIT**

In the XML file called course.xml, the title element is *IC 210 Fall 2010* and the contents of $course_title is **IC 210 Fall 2010** so the parsing of the php file appears to be correct and there does not seam to be any special characters like a **"** or **'**

I also tried putting everything on the same line and not luck... (I even made sure in the xml file that the <title> element had the text on the same line...

Comment: Can you please show us the HTML from before the echo statements?  The rendered output that you get from these echos would also be helpful.

Comment: Just a quick question, do you know what would happen when $course_title would contain a course name like 'class "foo>' or any other character which has special meaning in JavaScript/HTML? Since the answer might not lie in this it's still an important thing to realize.

Comment: It could be that there is something in `$course_title` that is causing the quotes to end early. Check the source code and see what's outputted. You may need to add slashes to the output depending on your server config.

Comment: Make sure that `.innerHTML = "Some text"` are on the same line because `.innerHTML = "\nSome Text\n"` won't work in javascript.

Comment: please show us the output of course_title

Comment: Yeah, to add to @PLB's suggestion, here's how you can put it all on one line: `$course_title = '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "'.$course_title.'";</script>";`. Note, the use of the period.

Comment: @PLB & skizeey YES! Thank you! I was a liar in my comment, I was editing the wrong element in my xml file... so the solution does appear to infact be that in my XML file, I cannot have a carriage return "\n" at all! I appreciate your help! Thank you! Please post as solution so I can accept that one if you have the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `.innerHTML = "Some text"` are on the same line because `.innerHTML = "\nSome Text\n"` won't work in javascript.

If you want to have something like this:

```
.innerHTML = "
Some String
";
```

try:

```
.innerHTML = ""+
"Some String" +
"";
```

Comment: For the record and anyone else out there who ever has this problem, I believe the main problem was in the XML file that I happen to be grabbing data from. I had new lines in the xml file between the tags and the data.

Comment: @Matthew I've not slept 2 nights because of the same problem (linebreak between data and datgs in xml) but our conversation is extremely off-topic. I am glad that I helped you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

"call some Javascript that will update the "innerHTML" of a DOM element." for that we use AJAX, no?

well you can do that way but i think it would be simpler to have the text preloaded in some hidden DIV's and use your functions just to change content's of the DIVS or even toggle visibility of the DIV (as you prefer). That way you will avoid many escaping problem's referred in the comments.

that's the way i would do it if not to use AJAX